# array is not rendering Properlyform controller to twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

`{{array.key}}` does not print value

This is My Twig File

```
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for count in 1..result|length %}
        <td>
        {% block tile %}
            {% include 'tile.twig' %}
        {% endblock %}
        <h1>{{ result.id }}</h1>
        </td>
        {% if count is divisible by (6) %}
    </tr>
        <tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This is My Controller

```
public function fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId( Request $request, Response $response ) 
{
        $args=$request->getParams();
        $args=$args['id'];
        $results = $this->m_objOlxUserDetails->fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId($args);

        return $this->view->render($response,'profile.twig',['result' => $results]);
    }
```

It display Nothing at place of `{{result.id}}`

And the ouput of var_dump($results); at controller is*

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#157 (1) { 
        ["id"]=> int(1) 
        } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#185 (1) { 
        ["id"]=> int(2) 
        } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#186 (1) { 
        ["id"]=> int(4) 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `result` is **array of objects**, `result.id` **does not exist**, you should use

```
<h1>{{ result[count - 1].id }}</h1>
```

I substract `1` as your `count` starts from **1**, and indexes in array start from **0**.

Comment: and what if i am not fatching array of object and fetch through (PDO::fetch_ASSOC);

Comment: I suppose it is `<h1>{{ result[count - 1]['id'] }}</h1>` but you can try and check.